# Running gem5 with DramSim2

Tags: linux, memory, simulation, gem5

So I've been able to build gem5 and run full system simulation . Now i want to integrate it with dramSim2 .I cloned the dramsim2 into ext directory in gem5. I ran the following command to build the .opt file 
again 
      scons build/ARM/gem5.opt
The error it throws is -

```
 build/dramsim2/DRAMSim2/BusPacket.cpp: In member function 'void 
 DRAMSim::BusPacket::print(uint64_t, bool)':
 build/dramsim2/DRAMSim2/BusPacket.cpp:63:2: error: nonnull 
 argument 
 'this' compared to NULL [-Werror=nonnull-compare]
 if (this == NULL)
 ^~
 build/dramsim2/DRAMSim2/BusPacket.cpp: In member function 'void 
 DRAMSim::BusPacket::print()':
 build/dramsim2/DRAMSim2/BusPacket.cpp:104:2: error: nonnull 
 argument 
'this' compared to NULL [-Werror=nonnull-compare]
if (this == NULL) //pointer use makes this a necessary precaution
^~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
scons: *** [build/dramsim2/DRAMSim2/BusPacket.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Anyone know what it means ?

Comment: I recommend asking this on the mailing list. cc whoever is responsible for dramsim based on git blame and dramsim repo. Say what OS and compiler version and gem5 version and dramsim version you are using on the report.

Answer (score 0):

Dramsim2 is outdated, and its original author stop actively maintaining the project. Although you may want to fix the codes as described [here](http://Although%20can%20you%20test%20if%20the%20build%20passes%20the%20failure%20point%20by%20giving%20-Wno-nonnull%20compilation%20switch?), can you simply test if the build passes the failure point by additionally giving -Wno-nonnull compilation switch?

Comment: Hi, the keyword "here" has a failure hyperlink. Where does it link to originally?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem . I changed gcc, g++ version.
I changed gcc version from `6.0` to `4.8`.

Use this command and change the version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc

sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```